# Why does "whatsapp" get "Permission denied" for readable system files?

Tags: permissions, whatsapp

```
$ sudo snap install whatsapp-for-linux
…

$ whatsapp-for-linux 
/home/ray/Music was removed, reassigning MUSIC to homedir
Gtk-Message: 19:18:53.036: Not loading module "atk-bridge": The functionality is provided by GTK natively. Please try to not load it.
…
<13>Jan 24 21:11:19 whatsapp-for-linux[1247241]: ** (whatsapp-for-linux:1247170): WARNING **: 21:11:19.257: Could not open /sys/class/dmi/id/chassis_type: Failed to open file “/sys/class/dmi/id/chassis_type”: Permission denied
<13>Jan 24 21:11:19 whatsapp-for-linux[1247241]: 
<13>Jan 24 21:11:19 whatsapp-for-linux[1247241]: ** (whatsapp-for-linux:1247170): WARNING **: 21:11:19.257: Could not open /sys/firmware/acpi/pm_profile: Failed to open file “/sys/firmware/acpi/pm_profile”: Permission denied
…

$ ls -l /sys/class/dmi/id/chassis_type /sys/firmware/acpi/pm_profile
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Sep  4 09:35 /sys/class/dmi/id/chassis_type
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Sep  4 09:35 /sys/firmware/acpi/pm_profile
```

It shouldn't be opening them for writing or trying to execute them, so **why are those two system files getting "Permission denied"?**

Not as important:

The "was removed" is ambiguous: is it claiming to have removed it or to be unable to find it?
Either way, it's still there, a symlink to `/data/Music`.

And why "Music" and "MUSIC"?